# Multiple Queries in Oracle Database using Python

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g

How to execute all queries in one line instead of creating separate execute operation

```
import cx_Oracle 

if__name__="__main__"

try:
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('arslanhaider/12345@AHS:1521/XE')         
    cur = con.cursor()          
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Password(Username varchar(255),Password INT)")    
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Password VALUES('arslanhaider',12345)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Password VALUES('arslanhaider95',123456)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Password VALUES('arslanhaider143',123457)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Password VALUES('arslanhaider123',123458)")

    con.commit() 

except cx_Oracle.Error:
    if con:
        con.rollback()
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is cx_Oracle.Cursor.executemany, this is mainly useful when doing bulk inserts.

```
>>> create_table = """
CREATE TABLE python_modules (
module_name VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
file_path VARCHAR2(300) NOT NULL
)
"""
>>> from sys import modules
>>> cursor.execute(create_table)
>>> M = []
>>> for m_name, m_info in modules.items():
... try:
... M.append((m_name, m_info.__file__))
... except AttributeError:
... pass
...
>>> len(M)
76
>>> cursor.prepare("INSERT INTO python_modules(module_name, file_path) VALUES (:1, :2)")
>>> cursor.executemany(None, M)
>>> db.commit()
>>> r = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM python_modules")
>>> print cursor.fetchone()
(76,)
>>> cursor.execute("DROP TABLE python_modules PURGE")
```

Example code taken from [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html) article